# Is using lua's error(.., level) an anti pattern?

Tags: error-handling, lua, lua-5.1

Lua 5.1's API provides an [error()](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-error) function, which accepts a string (the error message) and a "level".

My understanding is that `level`, lets you move up the call stack, so you can provide nicer error reporting, especially when delivering a module as an API.

For example, imagine the user calls `api_function(x)` with `x = nil`. This will be an error, but the API doesn't know until it's quite a bit into it's code.

It may result in this call stack:

```
api_function(x)                     : user_file.lua:30
  -> api_function                   : api.lua:20
    -> some_function                : api.lua:250
      -> handle_when_x_string       : api_string.lua:20
        -> error("value is nil")    : api_string.lua:66
```

As written, the user will see something like `api_string.lua:66 error: value is nil`, when what they really want to see the "nice" error, `user_file.lua:30 error: value is nil`. ("Is that error my fault or a bug in the API?")

Now, we *can* change the code to "pop the call stack",

```
api_function(x)                     : user_file.lua:30
  -> api_function                   : api.lua:20
    -> some_function                : api.lua:250
      -> handle_when_x_string       : api_string.lua:20
        -> error("value is nil", 5) : api_string.lua:66
```

Which will return the "nice" error, *but*, imagine you can also call `handle_when_x_string` more directly (poor API design aside),

```
another_api_fn(x)                     : user_file.lua:44
  -> another_api_fn                   : api.lua:11
    -> handle_when_x_string           : api_string.lua:20
      -> error("value is nil", 5)     : api_string.lua:66
```

Now our "pop level" is incorrect. Perhaps in this example, it would simply pop to the top and stop trying, but the principle of "incorrect level" remains at least uncomfortable, it may even pop "out" of where the user caused the error.

I can see a few solutions:

- Don't set level and just assume the user is smart enough to work it out.
- Wrap anything below your api entry points (`api_function` & `another_api_fn`) in a pcall, catch any error and re-bubble with a known "good" level value.
- Don't ever error in lower api functions, always `return nil, error` or some similar pattern, then check for that in `api_function` and act as required.

My questions are:

- *Is* it a problem to return the wrong level? It seems poor form to just "yeah whatever" a number in there and hope it's good.
- If it is a problem,  when is it ever a good practice to set the level (beyond maybe 0 which disables location reporting)
- Which of the solutions, if any, are best practice? What should I actually do to write better maintainable code? Wrapping in pcall seems the easiest, since you can still rely on "normal errors" when testing and your functions are somewhat simpler, but somehow it feels like an antipattern, in my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to differentiate from errors due to a bad API call, and actual bugs in your code.

If the purpose of the `error` call is to tell the API user that they passed the wrong arguments, you should validate the arguments in every API function, so that the error level will be knowable, and so the rest of your library knows it's working with valid arguments. If you end up with a complicated hierarchy of validating functions, they can take parameters for the function name and error level. Here's a very contrived example for how you can use error levels:

```
local function lessThan100(x, funcName, errorLevel)
  if x >=100 then
    error(funcName .. ' needs a number less than 100', errorLevel)
  end
end

local function numLessThan100(x, funcName, errorLevel)
  if type(x) ~= 'number' then
    error(funcName .. ' needs a number', errorLevel)
  end
  lessThan100(x, funcName, errorLevel + 1)
end

-- API function
local function printNum(x)
  numLessThan100(x, 'printNum', 3)
  print(x)
end
```

If the `error` call represents a bug in your code, then don't use a level, because you can't know what triggers the bug.

Answer (score 3):

It is very uncommon in Lua to use `error()` to "bubble up" errors. It is much more common to return `nil` followed by a string describing the error, and leave it to the caller to decide whether the function failing is something it can recover from, whether it should try again, etc.

This is also more performant as it has less overhead than calling `error()` (It's just a normal function call)

Over-using `pcall` and forwarding errors is a very bad idea. It will just make your code much harder to follow.

Comment: Would be helpful to know why this was disagreed with.

Comment: @marksonedwardson I sure would love to know as well 

Comment: I'm the downvoter.  I disagree with the phrase "forwarding errors [with pcall] is a very bad idea".  I have tried to use pcall-less approach in one my project: every function returned `nil, errmes` in case of error, and after every function call I checked if returned value is nil to propagate the error further by `return`-ing the same `nil, errmes`.  It was **very** boring.  My code has grown up in size significantly.  I will never follow pcall-less approach again.  `error+pcall` is useful and necessary Lua feature.  I disagree that `pcall` would make your code much harder to follow.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a case of a specific tool that exists for a specific purpose.
From the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.5.html):

> The error function has an additional second parameter, which gives the
> level where it should report the error; with it, you can blame someone
> else for the error. For instance, suppose you write a function and its
> first task is to check whether it was called correctly:
>
> Then, someone calls your function with a wrong argument:
>
> Lua points its finger to your function---after all, it was foo that called error---and not to the real culprit, the caller.
> To correct that, you inform error that the error you are reporting
> occurred on level 2 in the calling hierarchy (level 1 is your own
> function):

No language is perfect, and sometimes the designers will create a powerful and potentially dangerous tool in order to solve a specific problem. (C# reflection, for example) In this case, it seems like the intent is to report bad API calls in the function that made the call instead of the function that received it. So, levels 1 and 2 are the only *intended* levels as per the documentation, but that doesn't mean that other use cases don't exist.

You already highlighted the ways that (mis)using this language feature can cause more problems than it solves (aka. misleading the user with an error code that doesn't make sense). The question of good practice is often quite subjective, but our job is to write good, maintainable, bug free code regardless of the language we use. The designers of the language obviously thought that it was a good idea to put this tool in your toolbelt. You can start by reading the manual, but beyond that, it's up to you to understand the tool and use it well. If you don't feel like the tool should exist, or you just don't feel comfortable using it, then just stick with one of the alternative approaches you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a problem to return the wrong level? It seems poor form to just "yeah whatever" a number in there and hope it's good.

No, other than causing confusion. Error messages are there to help, and if you go "whatever" they won't. From the implementation's perspective there is no risk: [`luaB_error`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_error) uses [`luaL_where`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lauxlib.c.html#luaL_where) to add the message with the error location. If you get too far, the information will be simply skipped:

```lua
function foo ()
   error("where am I", 7)
end
foo() -- lua: where am I
      -- stack traceback: ...
```

I have generally seen only levels 1 and 2, with latter usually used to indicate that the parameters passed to function were incorrect. But that's my observation with no particular data to support it.

As for the remaining questions, it's primarily opinion based. Use whatever fits you and your problem. Both `error()` and `nil` + message are reasonable approaches. You did great job researching it and seem to have a good enough understanding to decide.